# using keyword with class not allowed?

Tags: c++, using, friend

Hi I am trying to use a class nested in another one by using the `using`keyword.
Is that possible with classes? I know that `auto` would do that and it would work with namespaces and base classes and functions.

Is my assumption for classes incorrect?

I am returned the following error

```
 error: ‘CTest’ is not a namespace
```

Below the source code

```
class CB {
  public: 
   void foo();
};

class CTest  { 
  public:   
    void foo();
  private:
    class CA {
      public:
        void foo() ;
    };        
  private:
    class CB b_;

    friend class CTest::CA;
    friend class CB;
};

void CTest::foo() { b_.foo();}
void CTest::CA::foo() { std::cout << "ciao" << std::endl;}
void CB::foo() { using CTest::CA; CA a; a.foo();}   

int main() {
  CTest obj;
  obj.foo();
}
```

Comment: You could do `typedef CTest::CA CA;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11:

```
void CB::foo() { using CA = CTest::CA; CA a; a.foo();}
```

C++98:

```
void CB::foo() { typedef CTest::CA CA; CA a; a.foo();}
```

Comment: Ah! I see...easy solution I didn't thing about it. Thank yo very much.